# Join and where clause with parameters

Tags: sql

I have the next tables COMPI, PRO, COMPRADO and the next SQL Query and parameters fecha1,fecha2, comprador

This return syntax error in the query

What is wrong in this code ??  (is a string sql to ADODB VBA EXCEL MACRO)

```
SELECT DISTINCT compi.DOCCOMPI,compi.FECHCOMPI,compi.MACOD,compi.MANOM,compi.MAREF,
    compi.MADIM,compi.CPCOMPI,compi.MAUNI,pro.PRONOM,comprado.NOMBRE 
FROM comprado 
INNER JOIN compi ON comprado.CODIGO=compi.COMPRADOR 
INNERJOIN pro   ON compi.NITCOMPI=pro.PRONIT  
WHERE compi.TEMPCOMPI='h' AND 
    compi.FECHCOMPI BETWEEN " & "#" & fecha1 & "#" & 
    "AND " & "#" & fecha2 & "#" & " AND 
    comprado.CODIGO=" & comprador & "
```

Comment: Your `innerjoin` needs a space, and I'm sure the `" & "` stuff at the end isn't valid sql either.  It looks like MS Access VBA ?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Adomar tahnk you for your prompt answer i have the space and don't work

Comment: The code block posted isn't valid SQL, and it doesn't appear to be valid syntax for constructing a string either. I'd recommend you start with the actual SQL text you want to send to the database, just use literals to get something working. Once that's working, then work on getting variables into the statement; and be aware of SQL Injection vulnerabilities when you do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the space between the INNER JOIN and use single quotes for string instead of double quotes:

```
SELECT DISTINCT compi.DOCCOMPI,compi.FECHCOMPI,compi.MACOD,compi.MANOM,compi.MAREF,
    compi.MADIM,compi.CPCOMPI,compi.MAUNI,pro.PRONOM,comprado.NOMBRE 
FROM comprado 
INNER JOIN compi ON comprado.CODIGO=compi.COMPRADOR 
INNER JOIN pro   ON compi.NITCOMPI=pro.PRONIT  
WHERE compi.TEMPCOMPI='h' AND 
    compi.FECHCOMPI BETWEEN ' & "#" & fecha1 & "#" & 
    ' AND ' & "#" & fecha2 & "#" & ' AND 
    comprado.CODIGO=' & comprador & '
```